# What is alternative of attributes?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, annotations

Attributes helps us use class dependant values instead of instances and they help us carry some values without strong relation with our classes. But i found some restrictions on attributes. We are not able to change these values on runtime. So i am looking a way to use similiar concept to attributes as we have seen many example configure classes by fluent apis instead of attributes. Do you know such a ready library ? What is an alternative to use attribute concept for avoiding attribute restrictions ?

Comment: Can you give an example of something you have implemented with attributes but want to change at runtime?

Comment: @justin - I want to represent objects by a kind of xml output so i want to write some custom attributes for hold values but users should be able to change their object representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in some cases you *can* tweak attributes at runtime - for example via `TypeDescriptor` - but this only affects ComponentModel usage, not reflection usage. You can also write the attribute itself to do things like resx lookup for i18n purposes.

But other options:

- maybe a static property, perhaps following a naming convention
- a separate object model that talks about the types - a meta-model, so to speak
- a configuration file or similar

Any will work; which is best depends on exactly what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A good replacement of attribute in a plug-in architecture could be using smart naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but can't you just add properties with a public setter to your custom attributes? I just tried this on a implementation where I use attributes, and I am able to change this property at runtime without any problems.

Which values do you want to change?

Comment: But you have changed just instance's property value of attribute.

Comment: I see, so you need **persistancy** for modifiable members in your attributes. I know of no libraries that already implement this, but it seems possible. Your custom attribute can probably use any form (ini/resource file/serialization/...) to store it's internal values persistantly. I'm assuming simple XML serialization doesn't provide you with a solution, because you want to change the settings at runtime?

Comment: Yes, i wanted to able to change values on runtime. I think that i have to save values persistency so only questions appear in my mind is how to save them ? i think i will chose type's guid value for it.

Comment: Persisting your data can happen from a helper class using reflection. The class which does this knows the entire 'path' to the member with the applied attribute. This is unique and can be used as a clear representation as well. The persistant behavior could also be placed inside the custom attribute itself when you would pass a unique ID in the constructor. (E.g. a enum value.) This value can also be used for easier/refactorable access to the attribute. An example can be found [here](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/10/28/dependency-property-factory-part-3/).